# Pandas dataframes and PyCharm IntelliSense

Tags: pandas, pycharm, intellisense

When I create new dataframes from old ones, using concat or merge, PyCharm intellisense stops working for the resulting dataframe unless I explicitly pass it to a DataFrame constructor

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [11, 22, 33]}
d2 = {1: [4], 2: [5]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
df3_ = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0))
```

In the above example `df3` and `df3_` are the "same" dataframe, but intellisense only works on `df3_`. Am I doing something wrong? How can I avoid always having to call the `DataFrame` constructor and still get intellisense out of pycharm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to use [type hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html) like this:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)  # type: pd.DataFrame
```

Comment: # type: pandas.DataFrame didn't work but # type: pd.DataFrame did work (import as follows - import pandas as pd)